# Cannot Convert System.Datetime to string error

Tags: c#

I have this code, but I get an error:

> Cannot convert'System.DateTime' to 'string'.

I'm trying to fetch only time part from a date as `HH:MM` format.

```
IFormatProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

q.CIP_START_TIME = DateTime.ParseExact(q.CIP_START_TIME, "hhmm", provider);
q.CIP_END_TIME = DateTime.ParseExact(q.CIP_END_TIME, "hhmm", provider);
q.CIP_VRB_TIME = DateTime.ParseExact(q.CIP_VRB_TIME, "hhmm", provider);
```

Comment: is your `q.CIP_START_TIME` a `DateTime` already?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, you are trying to convert a something to date time, that should be a string, and assign it to the same something which should not be a string. On top of this, you have not given us the datatypes of the variables you are working with

Comment: Nobody ever reads exception message :( _"Cannot convert 'System.DateTime' to 'string'"_ means that CLR can' convert `DateTime` instance to `string`. If you will make just a little effort - you can find that [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) says that the first parameter of `DateTime.ParseExact(..)` method **must** be a `string`.

Comment: q.CIP_START_TIME is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the use of `ParseExact`. The format parameter tells .NET the format of the input, not the format of the output. The format of the output is always the same-- a binary DateTime object that contains both date and time.

To convert it back to a string you can use `ToString()`, passing a format specifier to emit only the hours and minutes:

```
q.CIP_START_TIME = DateTime.Parse(q.CIP_START_TIME).ToString("HH:mm");
```